# connect/twitter POST not redirecting to twitter authorisation

Tags: spring, twitter, spring-social

I have created my app on Twitter and now I want to user Spring-Social to manage user authorisations.

I follwed this basic tutorial [accessing twitter](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-twitter/). The REST Server starts up fine, I navigate to host:8080/connect/twitter the default view is rendered. The problem is that when I click the "connect" button I am redirectd back to the connect view and not to twitter.

I ran a POST through fiddler and I get a 
302 Location: http://localhost:8080/connect/twitter;jsessionid=XXXXXXX

My application.properties has `spring.social.twitter.appId=MY_VALID_ID
spring.social.twitter.appSecret=MY_VAID_SECRET
spring.social.auto_connection_views=true`

I would expect to be redirected to twitter for authorisation at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foolishly I had not included a value to the "Callback URL" when registering my app on Twitter. After adding a place-holder URL it is now working fine.

And as to be expected the actual callback URL used is the value submitted as "applicationURL". Thanks, I hope this help someone else.

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem. Were you getting the redirect to twitter for authorization before adding callback URL? I mean as I understand, callback comes into picture after you have granted the permission.

Comment: @dShringi after getting the twitter API, the request would not connect to the permissions screen but rather bring back the 302, I hope that is clear. So did you add the callback URL? In which case the cause is probably something else altogether.

Comment: AFAIK using `redirect:/connect/twitter`, spring social registers `ConnectController connect` which creates a `RedirectView` for oauth on twitter. And hence should be redirected for oauth using twitter, post which callback url comes into picture, am I correct? Yes, I have a added callback url to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/success`.

Comment: I will try assist as best I can, since I am no longer using the spring library, and you question is not very clear. Did you add that callback URL the apps.twitter? Either way twitter requires a public URL as callback. /connect/twitter will cause a check for current connections, if there is none a request will be made to oauth, then a redirect to twitter for authorisation. What error exactly are you getting? As a guide of the flow https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing remember that much of this is already handled by the Spring library

Comment: For the callback, we can use the locally hosted application url as well, its just that it will not work with `localhost`, you'd need to use `127.0.0.1` and I am not getting any error, just the 302, as you were getting. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the url for authorization from

```
 /connect/twitter
```

to

```
 /auth/twitter
```

Hope the security filter will listen your request.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure with the information you've given, but the most obvious thing I'd do next is compare what you've done with the "complete" code at https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-twitter/tree/master/complete. I just now checked out a clean copy of that, plugged in my app's credentials and tried it. It worked as expected.

When you POST through fiddler, where's that 302 coming from? Is it Twitter giving it? Or is it the app itself giving the 302?